# In how many ways can $10$ adults and $5$ children stand in a line ...

Tags: permutations

> In how many ways can $10$ adults and $5$ children stand in a line so that no two children are next to each other?

My solution: $_A_A_A_A_A_A_A_A_A_A_$

So I'm trying to follow this example:[Combination and Permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449511/combination-and-permutation), and write:

$10!/2!\cdot\binom{11}{5}\cdot 5!/2!$

Is this correct?

Comment: Is the $/2!$ from reversing the line?

Comment: Are the adults (and children) distinguishable, or are you merely looking for the number of ways to distribute "adult" and "children" tags to each of the 15 positions?

Comment: Stars and Bars.

Comment: The adults and children are distinguishable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $10$ adults can stand in $10!$ ways. The $5$ children have $11$ places to stand so that there is an adult next to them on either side. We can place the $5$ children in ${11\choose 5}$ ways and then order the $5$ children in $5!$ ways. Thus by the Multiplication Principle there are ${11\choose 5}\cdot 5!\cdot 10!$ ways to place the $10$ adults and $5$ children so that no two children are standing next to each other.